# Easier way to systematically create new nodes?

Tags: c#, tree, ienumerable

So for testing purposes I need to have three IEnumerables of type `<T>`. One with both branches, one with one branch, and one comprising of just the node. I have to create further tests in much larger tree structures that will require more iterations of different IEnumerables. Currently, my (working) solution looks something like this. But I can't help but think that I could be adding the branches one at a time and setting the IEnumerables equal to one another at each step, or something of that nature to speed up the process. Evidently a direct implementation of this wouldn't work as they are reference types so they'll end up with the same value anyways, and it would be rather messy anyhow, if I worked around it...leaving me a bit stuck. Is there any way to accomplish this in less cumbersome fashion?

```
// Create test IEnumerables for comparison (one full, one with one branch, one of just node)
List<T> testlistfull, testlist1branch, testlistnode;
testlistnode = new List<T>();
testlistnode.Add(node0);

testlist1branch = new List<T>();
testlist1branch.Add(node0);
testlist1branch.Add(branch1);

testlistfull = new List<T>();
testlistfull.Add(node0);
testlistfull.Add(branch1);
testlistfull.Add(branch2);

IEnumerable<T> testenumfull = testlistfull as IEnumerable<T>;
IEnumerable<T> testenum1branch = testlist1branch as IEnumerable<T>;
IEnumerable<T> testenumnode = testlistnode as IEnumerable<T>;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use implicitly typed arrays.  They infer their type from the values in the array initializer.

```
IEnumerable<T> testenumfull = new [] {node0, branch1, branch2};
IEnumerable<T> testenum1branch = new [] {node0, branch1};
IEnumerable<T> testenumnode = new [] {node0};
```

Or if they have to be of type `List<T>` for some reason.

```
IEnumerable<T> testenumfull = new List<T>{node0, branch1, branch2};
IEnumerable<T> testenum1branch = new List<T>{node0, branch1};
IEnumerable<T> testenumnode = new List<T>{node0};
```

You don't need the `as IEnumerable<T>` as simply assigning to a variable of that type will do the implicit cast.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea I could do that. Thanks!